# Kivy Problem how to call a function in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a Auto Spam app using Kivy, But i am getting problems that i cannot call a function in the same class or call a function from other function because they are not defined.

main.py

```
import pyautogui
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import BorderImage
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, CardTransition
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
        
class screen1(Screen):
    def spamnow():
        boolean = 'false'
        if self.ids.label.text == 'Not Working':
            boolean = 'false'
        if ids.label.text == 'Working':
            boolean = 'true'
        while boolean == 'true':
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.typewrite(self.ids.texts.text)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
    def spam(self):
        time = self.ids.time.text
        Clock.schedule_interval(spamnow(), time)



class AutoSpammerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(screen1(name='Main'))
        return sm
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AutoSpammerApp().run()
```

and the kv file is:

autospammer.kv

```
<screen1>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id:time
        hint_text: 'Put here how much seconds interval'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.35}
        size: 500, 40
        font_size: 24
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id:texts
        multiline: False
        hint_text: 'Put here your spam text'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.75}
        size: 500, 90
        font_size: 24
    Button:
        id:enter
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.20}
        size: 250, 58
        text: 'Activate'
        background_color: (0.2, 0.95, 0.1, 0.9)
        on_press:
            label.text = 'Working'
            label.color = (0.2, 0.95, 0.1, 0.9)
            root.spam()
            
    Label:
        id:label
        color: (0.95, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9)
        text: 'Not Working'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 100
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.75, "center_y" : 0.20}
        font_size: 24
        
    Button:
        id:close
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.10}
        size: 250, 58
        text: 'De-Activate'
        background_color: (0.95, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9)
        on_press:
            label.text = 'Not Working'
            label.color = (0.95, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9)
            root.spam()
```

The main problem is the `Clock.schedule_interval(spamnow(), time)` the `spamnow()` function won't be called.

Any solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass the corresponding function to `Clock.schedule_interval` not what that function returns and the time as a numeric type. Replace `Clock.schedule_interval(spamnow(), time)` with `Clock.schedule_interval(self.spamnow, float(time))`. Also change `def spamnow():` to `def spamnow(self, dt):`.

Comment: Thank you @ApuCoder my problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call it with self, eg. self.spamnow(), don't forget that you are trying to call a member of that class.

Comment: Hello, i added self in ```spamnow()``` and in ```Clock.schedule_interval(spamnow(), time)``` the app freezed upon clicking the button.